# Mapbox GL / separation of style and data

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I have played with Mapbox and can quite easily create a Choropleth map in Mapbox studio and interact with it in Javascript.

I would like to create Choropleth map of the states with the ability to change the colours of the states for 100 years of different data points. I'm not allowed to upload the data into Mapbox as its sensitive healthcare data and I can't get sign of for the $499 a month cost.

My idea is I create a mapbox style layer in MapBox Studio then push the data client side for each of the states depending on the year x that the user selects. I have seen quite a few cloropeth tutorials such as this https://www.mapbox.com/help/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-1/ but the data is added in through a layer in Mapbox Studio.

Does anyone have any ideas if this is possible? and perhaps any useful API requests which may help me achieve this https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/

Answer (score 1):

You could join local JSON data with vector tile geometries:

Here is a Mapbox example which shows how to achieve this:

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-join/